# WinRT element rendering bug

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a small issue with rendering of some elements on a WinRT application.

The page is loaded but the elements of my listview are randomly dimmed for a few seconds. Sometimes they appear in gray and sometimes they are fine.

For information I use image for my listview items backgrounds (weight of my image = 4ko). 
I also tryed to give them a fixed Width and fixed DecodePixelWith but it doesnt change anything.

Any tips for solving this issue ? [screen shot example of my bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4G6U.png)

Thanks everyone :p

Comment: done :p

I still have the same issue, and it start to happen with others listview... 

Anyone could help me ? I pray my god for him :)

Answer (score 0):

This one is the datatemplate (it's a short example of my XAML code)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewIntervention">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  NineGrid="50,50,170,50" Stretch="Fill">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage  UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Shadow/ListViewUnplanned.png"
                             DecodePixelWidth="1200" 
                             DecodePixelType="Physical"/>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                   <Grid x:Name="grid_with_some_buttons>
                   </Grid>
                </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and there is my listview :

```
        <ListView
            Name="DataListView" Grid.Row="2"
            Margin="35,10,15,0" IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewIntervention}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding InterventionsCollection}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" SelectionMode="Single">
        </ListView>
```

Atm my listView contain 350 items.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of writing an answer.